# Why do I need double pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, double

I don't understand why I need double pointers inside 'struct graph'. Is it because it allows me to access one of the nodes that I made inside the function makeGraph()?

If I use one pointer (struct node *adjList) then I can't set the nodes to NULL that I made inside makeGraph().

I got the code frome programiz.com and in the article that explains this code it says: Don't let the struct node** adjList overwhelm you. All we are saying is we want to store a pointer to struct node*. This is because we don't know how many vertices the graph will have and so we cannot create an array of Linked Lists at compile time.

If I do: graph->adjList[1] does it go to the address of the second node or goes it inside the node? (I'm talking about the nodes that I create inside makeGraph())

I understand the rest of the code. If anyone can help me it would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct node
{
    int vertex;
    struct node *next;
};

struct graph
{
    int numVertices;
    struct node **adjList; // <--- THIS ONE
};

struct graph *makeGraph(int vertices) // Creating a Graph
{
    struct graph *graph = malloc(sizeof(struct graph));
    graph->numVertices = vertices;
    graph->adjList = malloc(sizeof(struct node) * vertices); // creating the nodes

    for (int i = 0; i < vertices; i++)
        graph->adjList[i] = NULL; // Setting all nodes to NULL

    return graph;
}

void addEdge(struct graph *graph, int src, int dest) // Add Edge
{
        struct node *newNode = makeNode(dest);
        newNode->next = graph->adjList[src];
        graph->adjList[src] = newNode;

        struct node *newNode2 = makeNode(src);
        newNode2->next = graph->adjList[dest];
        graph->adjList[dest] = newNode2;
        return;

int main()
{
    struct graph *graph1 = makeGraph(4);
    addEdge(graph1, 0, 1);
    addEdge(graph1, 0, 2);
    addEdge(graph1, 0, 3);
}
```

Comment: It's a dynamically allocated array of pointers.

Comment: If you don't understand why, then you probably don't need them. I see no obvious need for them here, looks like obfuscation. They could seemingly as well have allocated an array of structs with `struct node *` and a single malloc call. Perhaps they did it this way to enable faster swapping between edges? Swapping pointers is faster than hard copy of structs. Though on the other hand, malloc overhead and fragmentation is slow too.

Comment: struct node ** adjList is an array of pointers of struct node, just like int *arr represents an array of integers. g->adjList[1] represents the second element of the array and it is a pointer to a struct node that is adjacent to the current node in the graph according to the general definition.

Comment: You are allocating the wrong size memory block for the adjacency list. It should be `graph->adjList = malloc(sizeof(struct node *) * vertices);` or equivalently (and better style) `graph->adjList = malloc(sizeof(*graph->adjList) * vertices);`.

Comment: You already quoted the explanation given by the site where you got the code.  What about that don't you understand?

Comment: The code is wrong. In `makeGraph`, it is allocating the _wrong_ amount of memory: `graph->adjList = malloc(sizeof(struct node) * vertices); // creating the nodes`. Based on the type of `graph->adjList`, it should be allocating _pointers_ to nodes. The `sizeof` and the comment are _incorrect_. The code should be `graph->adjList = malloc(sizeof(struct node *) * vertices);`. Or, better yet, `graph->adjList = malloc(sizeof(*graph->adjList) * vertices);` If the code is _truly_ as you have posted it, this sort of error indicates you should _forget_ this example/website.

Comment: @CraigEstey I already mentioned that, but the code is correct on the original website: https://www.programiz.com/dsa/graph-adjacency-list

Comment: Why do I have to allocate it in that way?

Comment: @IanAbbott It's a pity that OP didn't post the link himself/herself. You went the extra distance to track it down. So, the linked code is [more] reasonable and OP had a transcription error. And, the comment is coming from OP and not the link.

Comment: @YK **"Why do I have to allocate it that way?"** If you wanted to allocate a memory block for an array of 4 `int`s, you would use `malloc(4 * sizeof(int))`. If you want to allocate a memory block for an array of `vertices` `struct node *`'s, you would use `malloc(vertices * sizeof(struct node *))`. `sizeof(struct node *)` is the same as `sizeof(*graph->adjList)` (or `sizeof(graph->adjList[0])`). Note that the operand of `sizeof` is not evaluated (so those pointers are not dereferenced); only the type of the operand is used to determine its size.

Comment: You want a list of _pointers_ to nodes. Not a list of nodes. As it is, you allocate too much memory as `sizeof(struct node) > sizeof(struct node *)`. But, if the struct were: `struct node { int vertex; };`, then [on a 64 bit machine], you would allocate too little memory because now you have `sizeof(struct node) < sizeof(struct node *)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An adjacency list is being represented as a linked list of `struct node`. The list is accessed by a pointer to the first element of the list. (The pointer will be `NULL` when the list is empty.) The pointer has type `struct node *`.

The graph has a number of vertices as set in the `numVertices` member of `struct graph`. Each vertex needs an adjacency list, and each adjacency list needs a `struct node *`. So the graph needs an array of `struct node *` of length `numVertices`. The authors of the code chose to allocate the array dynamically as a separate memory block pointed to by the `adjList` member. The type of the `adjList` member is a pointer to the element type. The element type is `struct node *` so the type of the `adjList` member is `struct node **`.

---

There is another way to allocate the memory for the `struct graph` and its adjacency list. They could be allocated as single block by changing the `adjList` member to be a *flexible array member*, as shown below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct node
{
    int vertex;
    struct node *next;
};

struct graph
{
    int numVertices;
    struct node *adjList[]; // <--- FLEXIBLE ARRAY MEMBER
};

struct graph *makeGraph(int vertices) // Creating a Graph
{
    struct graph *graph = malloc(offsetof(struct graph, adjList[vertices]));
    graph->numVertices = vertices;

    for (int i = 0; i < vertices; i++)
        graph->adjList[i] = NULL; // Setting all nodes to NULL

    return graph;
}
```

`offsetof(struct graph, adjList[vertices])` is the offset in bytes from the address of a `struct graph` to the address of the `adjList[vertices]` array member element. Allocating a block of memory of that size is just large enough to hold a `struct graph` plus the array of pointers. Another way to specify the size is `sizeof(struct graph) + vertices * sizeof(struct node *)` or alternatively `sizeof(struct graph) + vertices * sizeof(graph->adjList[0])`, but I think using the `offsetof` macro is a more succinct way to specify the size.

Comment: Thank you I understand it now!